# How do I recover an impounded vehicle?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

My son's Deluxo that I paid a lot of money for, got impounded, and now we can not find it or get it replaced with insurance - Is there any way to get it back?

Answer (score 3):

The Impound Lot is located in the garages adjacent to the Police Station in Davis. One can either attempt to pay the fee (by interacting with the gate and driving out) or just sneaking into the impound lot and driving away (keep in mind that this will award a wanted level)

Alternatively one can call the Personal Assistant, and the assistant will recover the vehicle (for a fee)